# Find all (most) html codes using regex in one expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search through many documents and find all instances where an html code is specified, except when &gt and &lt are used.

The folloiwng search

```
&[a-z]*\;
```

matches all HTML codes, eg   &gt etc.

I would like to modify this search so I can say, give me all HTML codes EXCEPT &gt and &lt.  I need to be able to do this in one expression.

Using http://regexpal.com/ and the following as the sample text:

```
&nbsp;&gt;&lt;&trade;
```

Only the first and last codes should be highlighted

Comment: I'm feeding this into grepwin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `&[A-Za-z]+(?<!&gt|&lt);`

Comment: adding +(?<!&gt|&lt); causes no hits in regexpal, but seems to work in grepWin.  I guess you answered my question, but don't know why its not working on the test page.

Comment: &[A-Za-z]+(?<!&gt|&lt|&foo);   Why doesn't adding "foo" work?

Comment: It appears that regexpal doesn't support lookbehinds. It does support lookaheads, so try this instead: `&(?!gt;|lt;)[A-Za-z]+;`

Comment: If it has only "gt" and "lt" then its width is definitely 2, but if it also has "foo" then its width could be 2 or 3. Not all regex implementations can handle that uncertainty...

Answer (score -1):

Either the first letter is not 'g' or 'l' or the second is not 't' or it's more than 2 letters.  So:

```
&([a-fh-km-z][a-z]|[lg][a-su-z]|[a-z]{3,})[a-z]*;
```

If you need to match a single letter too you'll have to add alternative option for that.